# Changing default permalinks on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've recently purchased a theme on ThemeForest, a nice and clean real estate theme for one member of my family, but the theme is based on an english language.
I translated it with POedit but there is one problem remaining.

It seems that the permalinks are set to be site.com/properties/post-name with "properties" being a variable that I can't change.

No matter What I choose in the permalink section, it won't change it; I would like to know where are set those default settings.

Thanks

EDIT:

Here's the lines of codes responsibles for my headache (Thx McNab foir pointing it out)

```
if( !function_exists('wpestate_create_property_type') ):
function wpestate_create_property_type() {
register_post_type('estate_property', array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name'                  => __('Properties','wpestate'),
        'singular_name'         => __('Property','wpestate'),
        'add_new'               => __('Add New Property','wpestate'),
        'add_new_item'          => __('Add Property','wpestate'),
        'edit'                  => __('Edit','wpestate'),
        'edit_item'             => __('Edit Property','wpestate'),
        'new_item'              => __('New Property','wpestate'),
        'view'                  => __('View','wpestate'),
        'view_item'             => __('View Property','wpestate'),
        'search_items'          => __('Search Property','wpestate'),
        'not_found'             => __('No Properties found','wpestate'),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __('No Properties found in Trash','wpestate'),
        'parent'                => __('Parent Property','wpestate')
    ),
    'public' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'properties'),
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'comments','excerpt'),
    'can_export' => true,
    'register_meta_box_cb' => 'wpestate_add_property_metaboxes',
    'menu_icon'=>get_template_directory_uri().'/img/properties.png'
     )
);
```

After changing the slug to something else, the addresses become the right one, but all ending on a 404. Are my links already created now dead?

Comment: Its a custom post type. It is unlikely to be changeable via config -  look in the theme files for register_post_type , the Properties post type will be set there and the `properties` will be the slug - https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

Comment: Considering that's it's a really complex theme, what are the odds of having to change anything else that this ? (thanks by the way)

Comment: No worries. That should do it - the only other thing you normally have to do is go to the Settings -> Permalinks page in the admin. Its a kind of Wordpress bug, just visiting the page flushes the permalinks so the new slug should be used instead.

Comment: @McNab Well i've modified it. The links are site.com/mynewslug/postname but every links get me a 404 error when I'm trying to access one of those properties.

Comment: As @McNab already pointed that after doing the change, you need to visit Settings -> Permalinks page in the admin.  this will refresh the Rewrite rules and your new rules will apply and 404 will go away.

Comment: @Mohsin Unfortunately that didn't work. I even flushed all cache and check from another navigator and same result.